# Is there any plugin event which can trigger before i log into the OctoberCMS Admin OR after the framework has dispatched the application

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I am trying to develop a plugin functionality in which I want to echo something before anyone logs into OctoberCMS Admin? Is there any plugin event or anything available?

In Joomla CMS there is an event called onAfterDispatch where the event is triggered after the framework has dispatched the application.

I need something similar to this in October CMS

Tried 'backend.page.beforeDisplay' event but this triggers after the user has logged into OctoberCMS Admin.

Event::listen('backend.page.beforeDisplay', function()

Expected Result - I need to echo something before I can be logged into the October CMS Admin

Actual Result - Can't echo anything before the user has logged in on October CMS Admin Screen

Answer (score 0):

The `backend.page.beforeDisplay` event is what you're looking for, but you need to make sure that your plugin has [elevated permissions](https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/registration#elevated-plugin) first so that your listener is registered.